# When does databinding and validation occur in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I recently went thru spring MVC doc and go to know below request processing flow under DispatcherServlet

> 1)Creates the Request Context
>
> 2)Locate the Handler/Conroller thru Handler mapping prepared at
>   context start up
>
> 3)Exceute Interceptors preHandler method if configured
>
> 4)Execute Handler/Conroller method
>
> 5)Exceute Interceptors postHandler method if configured
>
> 6)Handles Exceptions if any
>
> 7)Renders View
>
> 8)Exceute Interceptors afterCompletion method if configured

Now i have below method

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/userHistory", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody UserDetails getUserHistory(Model model, @valid UserDetail userDetail HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      model.addAttribute("userDetail", new userDetail());
    }
```

My question is at what point of time in above request processing flow, DispatcherServlet binds the data from request to model and userDetail objects?

Similarly at what point dispacherservlet triggers the validation on UserDetail object annotated with valid annotation?

**UPDATE:-** Say i have set the customValidator under controller method like this. Now at what point of time `customValidation`
 and `InitBinder` will be executed ?

```
    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(customValidator);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between the steps 3 and 4. Data binding is handled by argument resolvers. Those are also responsible for validation.

In your example you have the parameter `@valid UserDetail userDetail`. The default resolver used by Spring for that parameter is `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`. It binds the incoming form data to a `UserDetail` instance and if an `@Valid` or `@Validated` annotation is present it also validates the object. This implies that validation is not a separate step but either handled by an argument resolver or not at all.

After all argument resolvers have been executed the handler method is called with the resolved arguments.

Comment: `initBinder` is executed before the argument resolvers, because the binder is used by (some of) them. The validator is still called by the argument resolver (maybe indirectly through the binder).

Comment: so you mean to say that Initbinder method is executed between step 3 & 4. Then as we have registered customValidator
under initBinder. Once it is done validation is done , errors are added under binding results. Right?

Comment: @user3198603 `initBinder` is just a setup. You can define how things are done, like "use this validator" or "don't bind this property". The actual work is done by the argument resolver as described in the answer.